# Draw line in Google Earth that takes account of the globe's curvature

Tags: gis, kml, google-earth

I want to draw some lines that would follow either the longitude or latitude, but it doesn't take the globe's curvature in account.

How would I go about doing that? I'm using KML.

Answer (score 2):

In KML if you mean you want the line to clamp to the ground then you would set 'altitudeModeEnum' to 'clampToGround' and testate to 1 (true. Like so.

```
<LineString id="myLine">
  <tessellate>1</tessellate>
  <altitudeMode>clampToGround</altitudeMode>
</LineString>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [Gdal](http://gdal.org) to draw the line layer, and ogr2gor (same site) to convert the layer into kml

Comment: Just an update: I did it in Google Maps instead, where this is not a problem. Will check out your suggestion in the future though, thanks.

Comment: @ptm post your answer, and i'll delete mine

Answer (score 1):

You should try to break the line up with many vertices, so each one has an altitude. See [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/180323/google-earth-polygon-surface-area-to-follow-the-curvature-of-the-earth-model/192655#192655)